# Unable to read contents of artifact in GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: linux, bash, yaml, github-actions

I have an action download an artifact which is just a txt file. This action completes successfully and I can see the file extracted in the logs. I also have another step to run ls so I can confirm the file is listed in the directory.

```
      - name: Download PR ID
        uses: dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          search_artifacts: true
          name: number
          path: ${{ matrix.app }}
```

I can see the ${{ matrix.app }} resolves successfully to the right directory
as The ls command in the next step show in the logs the file is extracted, ;

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 runner docker   number.txt
```

However I can't use the contents of the file in the next step as it fails with a **cat: 113: No such file or directory**

This is the step I'm using;

```
      - name: Read number
        id: read-number
        shell: bash
        run: |
          PR_NUMBER=$(cat ${{ matrix.app }}/number.txt)
          echo "PR_NUMBER=$PR_NUMBER"
          echo "pr_number=$(cat $PR_NUMBER)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

I must be missing something obvious as this is all the same workflow, and I can see the txt file in the directory. How can I write the contents of this file to a variable that I can use in another step further down my workflow?

Comment: I know you added ls in another step, but could you add it just above this line `          PR_NUMBER=$(cat ${{ matrix.app }}/number.txt)`?

Comment: You try to `cat` a file named `113`, and there is no such file in the working directory. I would also print the working directory (for the safe side), and then check manually what files you have there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```yaml
      - name: Read number
        id: read-number
        shell: bash
        run: |
          PR_NUMBER=$(cat ${{ matrix.app }}/number.txt)
          echo "PR_NUMBER=$PR_NUMBER"
>>>>      echo "pr_number=$(cat $PR_NUMBER)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

Is trying to `cat` the contents of the file named `$PR_NUMBER`, in your case 113. You probably just want:

```
echo "pr_number=$PR_NUMBER" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

The error message mentions it can't find a file named `113`, but not that it can't find a file named `number.txt`.

Other than that, you're doing everything correctly.

Comment: Yep, I've modified it so now it works;

```
     - name: Read PR number
        id: pr-number
        shell: bash
        run: |
          PR_NUMBER=$(cat ${{ matrix.app }}/pr_number.txt)
          echo "PR_NUMBER=$PR_NUMBER"
          echo "PR_NUMBER=$PR_NUMBER" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```